# What is the determinant for Npgsql (C#) to select a connection pool?

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

We are running out of connections and I can't tell if we have a bunch of 1 connection pools, if pooling is not running, or if the connection pool is set to an unreasonably high number.

How does Npgsql determine when to pull a connection from a pool?

I'm new to this project, and this code was written by the ancients who have long-since ascended:

```
var conbuild = new NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
conbuild.ApplicationName += string.Format(":Framework[{0}:{1}]{2}", Environment.MachineName, 
Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId,_configurationHandler.Purpose);
connection = new NpgsqlConnection(conbuild.ConnectionString);
```

I'm thinking I'm getting a ton of 1 connection pools.

Can anyone corroborate my hypothesis?

Comment: You are missing `using` on your `connection` object, that will allow the internal (physical) connection to go back to the pool. There is normally one one pool per connection string (if the connection string changes you get a different pool). But you need to dispose the `connection` object otherwise it can't be reused.

Comment: Assume the connections are being disposed of correctly. Does the dynamic (per thread ID) ApplicationName translate to a different connection string and therefore a new/different pool?

Comment: I think it would be a different pool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, each connection string gets its own connection pool (barring some very specific exceptions).